# How to open an Ant file not part of eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

How can I open an `xml` that is an `ant` build file but is **NOT** part of an Eclipse project? It is just a file somewhere on the file system?

I can open it via Eclipse but I can not find an option to open it as `Open with-> Ant`

Answer (score 1):

You just open the file like normal XML. Then you must open view Outline to have access to the script targets.

Short cut for outline is 'Shift +Alt + O, Q' or from menu Window -> Show View -> Outline

Comment: That doesn't work. The various `${env.Path}` are not resolved

Comment: If ant is not part of any project, so it can not have any variables related to it. Thow you shold declare the manually.